# ICollection in a view ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I got the error:

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[CTCSAgenda.Models.Evenement]
```

message when I try to list my Icollection in a view.

Here's my Model Personne :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CTCSAgenda.Models
{
    // Classe Personne ayant une relation Many to Many avec la Classe Evenement, ce qui permet de générer une table intermédiaire Personne/Evenement lors de la génération des tables.
    // Etant donnée qu'une Personne peut s'inscrire à plusieurs Evenements et plusieurs Personnes peuvent s'inscrire à un même Evenement.
    // Il y a également une relation One to Many entre Personne et StatutPersonne
    // En effet, le statut est unique pour une Personne distincte et un statut peut être porté par plusieurs Personnes
    [Table("PERSONNE")]
    public class Personne
    {
        #region Properties nolink
        // Propriétés de la classe User
        [Key]
        [Column("ID_PERSONNE")]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdPersonne { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        [Column("NOM_PERSONNE")]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string NomPersonne { get; set; }
        [Column("PRENOM_PERSONNE")]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string PrenomPersonne { get; set; }
        [Column("LOGIN_PERSONNE")]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        [Display(Name = "Nom d’utilisateur: ")]
        public string LoginPersonne { get; set; }
#endregion
        #region Properties link
        // Lien Many to Many avec Evenement (Une personne peut s'inscrire à plusieurs Evenements)
        [Column("ID_EVENEMENT")]
        [ForeignKey("IdEvenement")]
        public virtual ICollection<Evenement> Evenements { get; set; }
        // Lien One to Many avec Statut (Une personne a 1 et 1 seul statut)
        [Column("ID_STATUT_PERSONNE")]
        public int IdStatutPersonne { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IdStatutPersonne")]
        public virtual StatutPersonne statutsPersonne { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

My model Evenement :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CTCSAgenda.Models
{
    [Table("EVENEMENT")]
    public class Evenement
    {
        #region Properties nolink
        [Key]
        [Column("ID_EVENEMENT")]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdEvenement { get; set; }
        [Column("TITRE_EVENEMENT")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Titre: ")]
        public string TitreEvenement { get; set; }
        [Column("DATE_EVENEMENT")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date: ")]
        // Pour afficher uniquement la date sans l'heure
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateEvenement { get; set; }
        [Column("HEURE_EVENEMENT")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Heure: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "hh:mm tt")]
        public DateTime HeureEvenement { get; set; }
        [Column("CAPACITE_EVENEMENT")]
        [Display(Name = "Capacité: ")]
        [Range(0,1000)]
        public int Capacite { get; set; }
        [Column("DESCRIPTION_EVENEMENT")]
        [Display(Name = "Description: ")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //[DefaultValue(0)]
        //[Range(0,1)]
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        [Column("IS_CANCELED")]
        [Display(Name = "Annulation: ")]
        public bool IsCanceled { get; set; }
#endregion
        #region Properties link
        // Lien Many to Many avec Personne
        [Column("ID_PERSONNE")]
        [ForeignKey("IdPersonne")]
        [Display(Name = "Participants: ")]
        public virtual ICollection<Personne> Personnes { get; set; }
        // Lien One to Many avec Lieu
        // Foreign Key pour Lieu
        [Column("ID_EVENEMENT_LIEU")]
        public int IdEvenementLieu { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IdEvenementLieu")]
        public virtual Lieu lieux { get; set; }
        // Lien One to Many avec CategorieEvenement
        // Foreign Key pour Categorie
        [Column("ID_EVENEMENT_CATEGORIE")]
        public int IdEvenementCategorie { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IdEvenementCategorie")]
        public virtual CategorieEvenement categoriesEvenement { get; set; }  
#endregion
    }
}
```

My ViewModel :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CTCSAgenda.Models;

namespace CTCSAgenda.ViewModels
{
    public class MesEvenementsViewModel
    {
        public Personne Personne { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Evenement> MesEvenements { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's my Controller :

```
public ActionResult MyEvents()
{
    var mesEvenementsViewModel = new MesEvenementsViewModel();
    Personne personne = (Personne)Session["User"];
    Personne dbPersonne = db.Personnes.Find(personne.IdPersonne);
    Personne personneVM = db.Personnes.Include(e => e.Evenements).First(e => e.IdPersonne == personne.IdPersonne);
    mesEvenementsViewModel.Personne = personneVM;
    mesEvenementsViewModel.MesEvenements = personneVM.Evenements;
    return View(mesEvenementsViewModel);
}
```

And finally My view :

```
@model CTCSAgenda.ViewModels.MesEvenementsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyEvents";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Les évènements auxquels je suis inscrit: </h2>

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MesEvenements)
<br />


        <table>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.MesEvenements)
                {
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TitreEvenement)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DateEvenement)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.HeureEvenement.TimeOfDay)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Description)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => item.Personnes)</td>

                }
            </tr>
</table>
```

I'm a beginner so there are probably some mistakes but everything is ok except the list of Personnes from an event. I got the message with HashSet and I don't know hot to list my Personnes...

Comment: That's not the entire error. Show the full error text and relevant source lines.

Comment: That's all I get on my browser when it comes to show the list of Personnes.

Comment: That's not an error, it's the view implicitly calling `ToString()` on your HashSet object.

Comment: And there's no code printing a HashSet in the code you show.

Comment: @CodeCaster But there is `ICollection` which can store a `HashSet`.

Comment: @Xr4y No offence, but you've now asked 7 or 8 questions about this fairly trivial bit of code. I know you are a beginner, but shouldn't you focus on learning how to do this stuff rather than asking us to help?

Comment: Thanks, that's what i'm trying to do for days...

Comment: Could you solve your problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Evenements collection has not been enumerated when you assign it to the VM.
Try the following in the controller:

mesEvenementsViewModel.MesEvenements = personneVM.Evenements.ToArray()

Comment: Yeah, that is probably not the problem. Try adding a [DisplayName("...")] attribute to MesEvenements in the ViewModel. I Think what you are seeing is not an error, but the result of DisplayNameFor(m => m.MesEvenements).

Comment: Nop if I add `<td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.Personnes)</td>` I got Participants : `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[CTCSAgenda.Models.Evenement]`

Comment: Isn't System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[CTCSAgenda.Models.Evenement] the message that you got initally? This happens because you define [Display] attributes only in your entity models, not in your viewmodels.

Comment: To be more clear, my hypothesis is that the "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[CTCSAgenda.Models.Evenement]" message you are seeing is not an error, but Razor printing the type name of a property you are trying to access with DisplayNameFor() or DisplayFor(). Make sure you have an [DisplayName()] attribute on the property when using DisplayNameFor(). Also you need a Display Template (under Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates) that matches the type of the property when you are calling DisplayFor().